# oneliner to get biggest something in a list

Tags: c#, algorithm

I searched on the web and can't really find if this exists.. I don't know if this is a good question but I'll try anyway.

What would be a oneline algorithm to retreive the biggest something in a list in c#.

Transforming something like this:

```
int currentRow = 0;
  foreach (CustomField cf in fieldList)
    if (cf.Row > currentRow)
      currentRow = cf.Row;
```

In this, Row is of Type int.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Linq ([Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
int currentRow = fieldList.Max(cf => cf.Row);
```

Note: source sequence should be not empty. If sequence can be empty, and you want to have some default value as max (i.e. `0` in your sample) then project sequence and use [Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int currentRow = fieldList.Select(cf => cf.Row).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

Comment: Pretty cleaver, I like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want the *element* with the largest value for some property (say, a Salesperson with the largest total sales) rather than just the max value itself,

```
public static TEntity MaxBy<TEntity, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TEntity> source, 
        Func<TEntity, TKey> selector) where TEntity : class
{
    if (source == null || !source.Any())
        return default(TEntity);
    return source.OrderByDescending(selector)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
List<Salesperson> allSalespeeps = GetSalespeople();
Salesperson winner = allSalespeeps.MaxBy(s => s.TotalSales);
```

Comment: `TEntity` can be value type. You should return `default(TEntity)`. Also `OrderByDescending` will create sorted collection. I would go with implementation of MaxBy suggested by MoreLINQ

Comment: Good point; I omitted the `where TEntity : class` from my code sample for brevity, but I've added it back now, along with your suggested change to `default(TEntity)`.